# How to retrieve data from Firebase database by passing a variable to reference.child()?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-vision

I have created an app that scans QR codes using Google Vision API and pass the QR value to Firebase real-time database.The retrieved data is displayed inside TextViews. However values are not retrieved from Firebase if a variable is passed as a child when referencing the database. How to set a variable as a child when referencing the database?

**Note: There is no problem with the database because data gets retrieved when passing a string as child**

This app uses google Vision API to scan QR codes.All dependencies are updated to latest versions and no exceptions are shown as well.

**NOT WORKING(When variable QRCODE is passed as a child) class name=AnimalInfo**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animal_information);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    animalClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aniClass);
    animalFamily = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aniFamily);
    animalOrder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aniOrder);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    QRCODE = intent.getStringExtra(QrScanner.QR_CODE);

    DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = DB.getReference().child("Animals").child(**QRCODE**);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String DBAnimalClass = dataSnapshot.child("class").getValue().toString();
            String DBAnimalFamily = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue().toString();
            String DBAnimalOrder = dataSnapshot.child("order").getValue().toString();

            animalClass.setText(DBAnimalClass);
            animalFamily.setText(DBAnimalFamily);
            animalOrder.setText(DBAnimalOrder);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**WORKING(When String is passed as a child)  class name=AnimalInfo**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animal_information);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    animalClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aniClass);
    animalFamily = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aniFamily);
    animalOrder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aniOrder);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    QRCODE = intent.getStringExtra(QrScanner.QR_CODE);

    DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = DB.getReference().child("Animals").child(**"00000001"**);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String DBAnimalClass = dataSnapshot.child("class").getValue().toString();
            String DBAnimalFamily = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue().toString();
            String DBAnimalOrder = dataSnapshot.child("order").getValue().toString();

            animalClass.setText(DBAnimalClass);
            animalFamily.setText(DBAnimalFamily);
            animalOrder.setText(DBAnimalOrder);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**QRScanner class: gets QR code and pass it to AnimalInfo class using intent**

```
@Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if(qrCodes.size()>0)
            {
                qrResult.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        qrResult.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QrScanner.this,AnimalInformation.class);
                        intent.putExtra(QR_CODE,qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I want to pass QR code value as the reference for database so it gives data according rather than hard coding the reference.

**Another Problem: AnimalInfo layout gets created several times when its loaded upon starting the intent in QRScanner.java and I have to press the back button several times to go to Home page.**

Comment: Why do you use ** QRCODE ** and not just QRCODE?

Comment: Try creating String QRCODES = "00000001" and passing it as the value to check if it works.

Comment: @guy I just used **** to show that this is the one affected, In the actual code there is no ****

Comment: Assigning QRCODES = "00000001" and placing the variable inside child doesn't work too

Comment: Could you please post a sample of your data in firebase?

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo